# Как найти нужное по счёту слово в строке (php)?

Tags: php, строки

Вводится строка с пробелами. Собственно говоря, нужно изъять из этой строки некое n-ное по счёту слово (n всегда разное). Ну или найти n-ный пробел. Есть ли какая-нибудь встроенная функция в php (не explode()) для реализации этой задачи?

Comment: А чем вам explode не нравится?

Comment: При длинной строке уходит много памяти

Comment: Спасибо всем. Переписал на pascal'e

Answer (score 6):

Зачем тут `explode` и регулярки?

Вариант на коленке, в таком виде съедает памяти "самое длинное слово + несколько `int`", т.е. вряд ли больше 1кб.

```
function getWord($string, $WordINeed) {
  $CurrentWord = 0;
  $LastReadWord = $tmp = '';
  $ln = strlen($string);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $ln; $i++) { // бежим по буквам
    if ($CurrentWord == $WordINeed) // если слово достигнуто,
      break; // выходим из цикла
    if ($string{$i} == ' ') { // если пробел - пишем последнее слово 
      $LastReadWord = $tmp; // в переменную
      $tmp = ''; // и читаем заново
      $CurrentWord++; //следующее слово
      continue;
    }
    $tmp .= $string{$i};
  }
return ($CurrentWord == $WordINeed) ? $LastReadWord : false;
}
```

Comment: > `function getWord(&$string, $WordINeed) {`

Скажите, чем вы руководствовались, когда ставили `&`(амперсанд) в первом параметре?

> Вариант на коленке, в таком виде жрет памяти "самое длинное слово + несколько int"

Не правда ваша. В таком виде он жрет "самое длинное слово + несколько int + strlen($string) * 2". Т.е. если брать строку (как тут многие умники предлагают) в 100мб, то памяти будет использовано 200мб

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov , руководствовался как раз памятью. Т.к. за время работы функции строка не изменяется, при передаче по ссылке она не будет скопирована. Если добавить хотя бы `$string .= ' ';`, вы были бы правы) (*Update, засомневался. Насколько помню, надо прямо создать копию, чтобы скопировать, что-то хабровское меня запутало.*)

Comment: Вообще, конечно, оперировать данными такого объема в php лучше через файлы, тогда использование памяти будет минимальное(за счет скорости, и то не факт). А то на хостингах за такие "поисковые работы" можно и по ушам схватить)

Comment: Смысла передачи ссылки не вижу. ( с учетом того, что ссылка в PHP, мягко говоря != ссылка в С++ )

Comment: @Sh4dow - если мне нужно было бы обрабатывать строки такой длины, не думаю что у меня было бы такое ограничение ОП =)

Да и не на php я бы это писал

Comment: @Sh4dow, вам читать матчасть [**о том как работают переменные в php**](http://derickrethans.nl/php-references-article.html) еще раз.

В PHP **все переменные всегда передаются по сыылке** и копируются только при изменении. Единственное исключение из это правила - это использование жесткой ссылки (`&`). При использовании **жесткой ссылки создается еще одна копия переменной**, даже если вы не ее не меняли. По этому использование `&` в вашем коде не только не экономит память, но и **увеличивает ее расход в два раза**, по сравнению тем же кодом без `&`. В общем, внимательно читайте ссылку выше.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - как раз искал этот линк

Comment: [тыц](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test45.php) еще вопросы будут?

Comment: Раздел "Mixing Assign-by-Value and Assign-by-Reference"

> In step 2 we proceed by assigning variable $c by ref-
erence to variable $b. Here, the PHP engine will create
a copy of the variable container.

> тыц еще вопросы будут?

Этот тест доказывает лишь ваше непонимание принципов работы с переменных в PHP :) Разнесите ваши тесты по разным файлам, и посмотрите, что получится:

[test 1](http://codepad.org/WnntL6aH)

[test 2](http://codepad.org/cfTAXed9)

Эти тесты различаются одним символом.

    Алгоритм:         5/5
    Реализация:       2/5
    Написание тестов: 1/5

Comment: =( Принято, разнес по файлам, в той же ссылке. Блин, я до последнего не верил, что у php все настолько плохо. Таки шаблонизатор.

*Исправил в коде, ушел грустить.*

Answer (score 3):

```
$number = 10;
preg_match('/(?:[\wа-я]+\b.*?){'.($number - 1).'}([\wа-я]+\b)/ui', $string, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

UPD.

Та-же самая регулярка без флага u.

```
$string = 'Верховое болото в связи с преобладанием карьерной разработки ископаемых горизонально слагает тектогенез, поскольку непосредственно мантийные струи не наблюдаются. Из-за такого рода побочных факторов авгит пластично поступает в сталагмит, поскольку непосредственно мантийные струи не наблюдаются. Диабаз выдержан. Оледенение стягивает интрузивный авгит, что лишь подтверждает то, что породные отвалы располагаются на склонах. Магматическая дифференциация контрастна.';

$string = str_repeat($string, 500000);
var_dump(strlen($string)); // int(434000000) ~413мб

$number = 1000;

$t = microtime(true);
preg_match('/(?:.\s.*?){'.($number - 1).'}(\S+)/s', $string, $m);
var_dump(microtime(true) - $t); // float(0.00081992149353027)
```

Comment: И строку туда в 100мб xDDD

Comment: Советую вам почитать, как работают регулярки. Даже если на входе будет строка 100гб, на скорость работы самой регулярки это *никак* не повлияет. 

Другое дело, что при использовании флага 'u', требуется некоторое время на обработку строки (хотя даже строк в 100мб - это миллисекунды).

Comment: Я не о скорости работы, за совет спасибо - будет время погуглю
****
@Ilya Pirogov - если обладаете ценной ссылкой на эту тему - прошу поделиться

Исходя из моих скромных знаний - чудес не бывает и все-равно это цикл. Примерно такой-же как в ответе @Sh4dow (абстрактно)

Comment: > Исходя из моих скромных знаний - чудес не бывает и все-равно это цикл. Примерно такой-же как в ответе @Sh4dow (абстрактно)

Именно так. По этому, данная регулярка (как и код @Sh4dow, но с поправкой на жесткую ссылку), отработает быстро и с минимальными затратами памяти хоть на 100мб, хоть на 1000мб строке.

Comment: Книгу тоже можно, главное что-бы интересная была =)

Comment: Прошу прощенья, забыл совсем про книгу.

[Идеальный код](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5686555/) под редакцией Энди Орама и Грега Уилсона. Не путать с книгой "Совершенный код" Макконнелла. Это совершенно другая книга от различных известных программистов, затрагивающая самые разные аспекты программирования.

Про регулярные выражения там лишь одна глава, но очень познавательная. Остальные главы то-же интересные, но стоит предупредить, что там используются ЯП от C до Haskell. По этому  желательно уметь, если не читать, то хотя бы не пугаться листингов на других языках.

Answer (score 2):

А какого размера у вас строка? Я только что специально попробовал - на трёхмегабайтной строке специализированная функция [`str_word_count($строка, 1)[$номерслова];`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-word-count.php) работает почти в два раза медленнее чем [`explode(' ', $строка)[$номерслова];`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php). А если у вас строки по 100 Мб, тогда лучше задуматься об оптимизации алогритма, чем искать в них слова...

Comment: Если строки по 100мб тогда явно писать надо не на PHP

Answer (score 1):

Нет такой функции...

Можно по циклу прогнать заменив пробелы на другой(ие) симвл(ы).

Comment: Жаль. Уйдёт ещё больше времени и памяти

Answer (score 1):

Регулярки
Но это еще массивнее чем эксплод получится.